# Is there a way to use values of a .txt file to populate a graph in php?

Tags: php, charts

Is there a way to use a numeric value of a .txt file to populate values on a php graph?

currently have the graph set up, see code below. I just need to figure out how I can get (value 1), (value 2), (value 3) to be populated by txt files on my server.

```
    <?php

    $dataPoints1 = array(
        array(
            "label" => "column1",
            "y" => (value 1)
        ),
        array(
            "label" => "column2",
            "y" => (value 2)
        ),
        array(
            "label" => "column3",
            "y" => (value 3)
        )
    );

    ?>
```

Comment: Why do you remove questions???? That's now stackoverflow reason to live. Keep it online for others to find a solution to your same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, i didn't test it, but should work
        $myFile = "file.txt";

```
    $json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($myFile), true);

    $value1 = $json_data['value1'];
    $value2 = $json_data['value2'];
    $value3 = $json_data['value3'];

    $dataPoints1 = array(
    array(
        "label" => "column1",
        "y" => $value1
    ),
    array(
        "label" => "column2",
        "y" => $value2
    ),
    array(
        "label" => "column3",
        "y" => $value3
    )
);
```

file.txt:

```
{"value1":1,"value2":2,"value3":3}
```